# Regex select one / but not multiple in js

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split a string at `/` but not at `//` or `///`.
What I tried:

1. `/[^\/]\/[^\/]/g` but I don't want the characters before and after the `/` to be selected.
2. `/\b\/\b/g` not working because `\b` only counts for `\w`.
3. `/(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/g` but lookbehind is not supported in javascript.

I can't find a way to achieve my goal. Has anyone a solution to this or is this just not possible in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.match(/(?:\/{2,}|[^\/])+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO3X4F/2)

The `(?:\/{2,}|[^\/])+` pattern matches one or more (`+`) occurrences of 2 or more `/` chars or any char but `/`. This means it matches any char(s) up to a single `/`.

```js
var rx = /(?:\/{2,}|[^\/])+/g;
var s = "a/b//c///d////r";
console.log(s.match(rx));
```

Comment: Okay, now there is selected everything but a single /. But I actually want to select them. Is it possible to just negate the whole expression?

Comment: @S.Babovic You cannot use a `split()` method. Use `.match()` as I showed. Ok, in Chrome, there is a way to use a lookbehind (with some special option enabled), but it is still a non-standard construct for a JS regexp.